# Python : ( msg = email.message_from_string(aaa) ) values are returning ( None ) when trying to parse stuff from raw e-mail source

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

let's execute the script

```
python b.wsgi
```

result is:

```
None
None
```

that is the problem and here is the full script `b.wsgi`

```
aaa = """
From root@a1.local.tld Thu Jul 25 19:28:59 2013
Received: from a1.local.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id r6Q2SxeQ003866
    for <ooo@a1.local.tld>; Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r6Q2Sxbh003865;
    Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
From: root@a1.local.tld
Subject: oooooooooooooooo
To: ooo@a1.local.tld
Cc: 
X-Originating-IP: 192.168.15.127
X-Mailer: Webmin 1.420
Message-Id: <1374805739.3861@a1>
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="bound1374805739"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--bound1374805739
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

--bound1374805739--
"""

import email
msg = email.message_from_string(aaa)
print msg['From']
print msg['To']
```

i tried changing it to

```
print msg['from']
print msg['to']
```

same problem.

what might be the issue here ?

is it possible PYTHON knows this "raw" string was manually edited by my hands ?

very sneaky stuff going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\n` at the beginning and end of the string are causing the problem. Try this

```
>>> msg = email.message_from_string(aaa.strip())
>>> msg.keys()
['Received', 'Received', 'From', 'Subject', 'To', 'Cc', 'X-Originating-IP', 'X-Mailer', 'Message-Id', 'Date', 'MIME-Version', 'Content-Type']
>>> msg['From']
'root@a1.local.tld'
```

Comment: This answer helped me out perfectly, i simply removed the new lines instead of using the strip() but in the future i might use strip() if it comes down to it. - Sumer Kolcak